# Case statement in oracle

Tags: sql

Here's my queries, they don't work but I want to do something like this in sql (oracle)

`$P{parametre}` is a parameter used in jasper;

```
select val1, val2 from table where 
table.column1  =(case when  $P{parametre} is not null   then  $P{parametre}    end  )
and
table.column1 is not null (case when  $P{parametre} is null     end  )
```

but `table.column1 is not null (case when  $P{parametre} is null     end  )`  don't work

do you have  idea please??

Comment: `table.ID_table is not null (case when  $P{parametre} is null     end  )` what exactly are you trying here?

Comment: excuse me,  table.column1 not table.ID_table

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
...
where (column1 is null and $P{parametre} is null)
or column1 = $P{parametre}
```

Which matches column1 to the parameter, but treats both being null as a match.